# Replace the characters after the last underscore

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with the following structure. I want to replace the character(s) after the last underscore.

```
$string = ' 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_3} : {$9018049_text_53441884_3} 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_4} : {$9018049_text_53441884_4} 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_5} : {$9018049_text_53441884_5} 
  ';
```

For example, If I replace the character "5" with "DT5", the output should be

```
$string = ' 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_3} : {$9018049_text_53441884_3} 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_4} : {$9018049_text_53441884_4} 
   {$9018049_text_50024080_DT5} : {$9018049_text_53441884_DT5} 
  ';
```

I have tried with str_replace, but the output is

```
$string = ' 
   {$9018049_text_DT50024080_3} : {$9018049_text_DT53441884_3} 
   {$9018049_text_DT50024080_4} : {$9018049_text_DT53441884_4} 
   {$9018049_text_DT50024080_DT5} : {$9018049_text_DT53441884_DT5} 
  ';
```

This is not what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: include the curly bracket in the search and replacement string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well:

```
$string = str_replace('_5}', '_DT5}', $string);
```

if you want to do the same for each content between curly brackets whatever the number:

```
$string = preg_replace('~_(\d+})~', '_DT$1', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 0):

Using lookahead regex search for:

```
_5(?=})
```

And replace by:

```
_DT5
```

Here `(?=})` will make sure that to `_5` followed by `}`.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rC0eJ3/2)

Comment: The OP does not want the last underscore in the string, but the last one within the curly brackets.

Comment: Hmm I think I got misguided by title **Replace the characters after the last underscore**

Answer (score 0):

select last line:

```
\n.*$
```

replace regex:

```
_\d(?=})
```